# Can I make an App Engine model property call a function?

Tags: google-app-engine, dynamic, google-cloud-datastore, ranking

I'm implementing a frontpage with "hot" stories based on a certain ranking algorithm.  However, I can't figure out how to pass App Engine Datastore my own sort function (like I can in Python with sort(key=ranking_function)).  I want something like this:

```
class Story(db.Model):
    user = db.ReferenceProperty(User)
    text = db.TextProperty()
    def ranking(self):
        # my ranking function, returns an int or something
        return 1
    ranking = property(ranking_function)
```

So that I can later call:

```
Story.all().order("ranking").limit(50)
```

Any idea how to do this using App Engine Datastore models?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no built in property that handles this, but there's a library, [aetycoon](http://github.com/Arachnid/aetycoon), that implements DerivedProperty and other related properties that do what you want. [Here's](http://blog.notdot.net/2009/9/Custom-Datastore-Properties-1-DerivedProperty) an article on how it works.

Comment: I did this and it works wonderfully.  However, I'm adding alot of properties that seem to throw NotSavedErrors when I try to make a new object with some DerivedProperties.  The only solution is to wrap the entire thing in a try-except.  It works but it's slightly ugly.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you be more specific? What stacktrace do you get, and under what circumstances?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is possible with App Engine the way you describe it, but I think it is possible to achieve what you want.  You want the datastore to run your ranking function against every element in the datastore, every time you do a query.  That is not very scalable, as you could have millions of entities that you want to rank.

Instead, you should just have a integer property called rank, and set it every time you update an entity.  Then you can use that property in your order clause.

Comment: Thanks.  However, see the accepted answer for a really useful, nifty library!